# Duplicate Oracle DES encrypting in Java

Tags: java, oracle, encryption

I recently asked a question about Oracle Encryption.  Along the way to finding a solution for myself I decided to move the encryption (well, obfuscation) to the application side for certain tasks.

My problem is that the database is already encrypting data a certain way and I need Java code to duplicate that functionality, so that text encrypted by one system can be decrypted by the other and vice versa.

I want the encryption to be compatible with what the DB was already doing but couldn't find the documentation that describes exactly what Oracle is doing.  How do I replicate this in Java?

```
dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt(
  input_string => v_string,
  key_string => key_string,
  encrypted_string => encrypted_string );
RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(encrypted_string);
```

No matter what I try, it seems as if the Java DES encryption is different than Oracle's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this works:

```
KeySpec ks = new DESKeySpec(new byte[] {'s','e','c','r','e','t','!','!'});
SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey sk = skf.generateSecret(ks);
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0});
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT, sk, ips);
// or
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT, sk, ips);
```

The missing piece was the Initialization Vector (ips) which must be 8 zeros.  When you use null in Java you get something different.

Comment: 1. Fixed IV means that the first block's (8 bytes) ciphertext is always the same for the same plaintext block -- dictionary attack possible on the first block.
2. CBC mode means that an attacker can easily perform bitflips in the decoded plaintext (but runing the plaintext block preceding it).

Comment: As I said in the question, this is used more for obfuscation than true encryption.  Anyway the fixed IV is unavoidable as that's what Oracle does.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java in the database would have been another approach that would (should!) have guarenteed that the code (and hence results) would be identical.

Comment: True, but unfortunately in this scenario I was stuck with the existing encryption algorithm as described in the question.  I needed to do exactly what that was doing in Java.  In practice I think the more modern Oracle encryption can fully inter-operate with foreign encryption libraries such as Java's.