# Decrypting in JSP

Tags: jsp, oracle10g, encryption

How (using JavaServerPages) can I decrypt data that was encrypted with PL/SQL

```
dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt
```

The key is known. I'm new with JSP so please explain your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP Code to decrypt dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393397/jsp-code-to-decrypt-dbms-obfuscation-toolkit-desencrypt-oracle), see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This encryption method `dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt` allows you to have passwords or you say it strings in multiple of 8 characters only. So below I have coded a sample JSP page which shows u that a string is encrypted and decrypted..

**Pre-Requisite:** This code uses a library org.apache.commons.codec.binary, Download org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.5 binary file and place it in the lib folder.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.crypto.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.crypto.spec.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*" %>

    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Cheers! </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <%
        String algorithm1 = "DES";//magical mystery constant
        String algorithm2 = "DES/CBC/NoPadding";//magical mystery constant
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec( new byte [] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } );//magical mystery constant
        Cipher cipher;
        SecretKey key;
        String k="12345abc"; //Just a random pick for testing
        key = new SecretKeySpec( k.getBytes("UTF-8"), algorithm1 );
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance( algorithm2 );

        String str="test4abc"; //Test String, 8 characters

        cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv ); //normally you could leave out the IvParameterSpec argument, but not with Oracle

        byte[] bytes=str.getBytes("UTF-8");

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( bytes );

        String encoded = new String( Hex.encodeHex( encrypted ) );
        out.println( "Encrypted/Encoded: \"" + encoded + "\"" );



        cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv );    

        //byte [] decoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex( encoded.toCharArray( ) );
        byte [] decoded = Hex.decodeHex( encoded.toCharArray( ) );

        String decrypted = new String (cipher.doFinal( decoded ));
        out.println("DECRYPTED: \"" + decrypted + "\"" );
    }

    %>  
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

This should probably resolve your problem.
Cheers!